# InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0':

Tags: azure-logic-apps

InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value

i need to get json file from azure blob storage account and need to use that json file data

issue is

> InvalidTemplate. Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Parse_JSON' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'json' parameter is not valid. The provided value

[image]

i used to get the input from azure get content
**json(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))**

[image]

i tryed to get input from get blob content json(body('Get_blob_content_(V2)'))

i checked with inserd json file in parse json input it working

output from Get_blob_content_(V2)

Comment: Show us the output of the get blob content operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Get Blob Content(V2)` action then the outputs we get in `content-type: application/octet-stream`.

If you want to get the actual json file and Parse it, you could do the following-

[image]

[image]

By doing the above actions, I am able to get the data in expected format.

[image]

[image]

In this way, you can get the expected result.

Comment: i am getting error in Parse json 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u2OuxizifuGdCRlj5T9BDrDuwh9fGu9z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SureshSuji please share the Json value you are passing in `content`

Comment: one special character in that string  that is the issue, how to fix it
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eXZnySNFv1xFX4dMOy0VJMgxs5bOpUYu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share the content value not the schema. I need the payload which is there in content

Comment: please find here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KFxb7ie3v66H2ACfWeJ-QOW89aBZlMtd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I need whole payload of Parse_Json content field which is partially visible here in https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u2OuxizifuGdCRlj5T9BDrDuwh9fGu9z/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19usCk0jC9805T2b2Ydpvs4PZnAUf0y8A/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please check a unique symbol in firs line start
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNZyB-5Nhoaij1GhgFHmKQSnxRYMNP9b/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please check the content stored in your blob, I believe this symbol is getting populated from the blob data